# Perl: processing files from the command line with -e. How is the passed file accessed?

Tags: perl, command-line, file-access

When I invoke Perl like

```
perl -e '' foo.txt
```

How is foo accessed?

If I use -i, I can edit foo.txt in place. I suppose foo.txt is associated with some file handle and opened for direct access? What would be the handle? If I use -0777, is the file streamed from STDIN (say) and stored in a scalar string or is it opened and read into such a string? Which string?

I understand this may be trivial but I can't seem to find answers.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here: "is the file streamed from STDIN (say) and stored in a scalar string or is it opened and read into such a string?"

Comment: Your answer clarified this to me. I more or less knew the file would at some point be read as a single big line and stored in a string. I wasn't sure how exactly this would happen. It seemed natural to conclude that the file name would be in an array of arguments and the file would be subsequently opened and read (as in the normal way of doing this). I just thought that maybe with -0777 the file would be read from the standard input as if I had typed it. I know, bizarre. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How is foo accessed?

It's in [`@ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@ARGV), as usual (specifically `$ARGV[0]`).

`-i` doesn't really operate in place. It renames the original file out of the way and creates a new file with the original name. The input handle for the pseudo-file formed by the concatenation of all files in `@ARGV` is called `ARGV`; the output handle for `-i` processing is called `ARGVOUT`.

`-0777` just sets `$/` (also known as the input record separator) to `undef`, which causes [`readline`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html) to return the whole file as a single "line".

For more information, see

- [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)
- [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Comment: The references are very good. The handle proper is ARGV then. Should I have read the explanation for -i in perldoc/perlrun, I wouldn't have asked this question. The bit about -0777 and readline totally clarifies my doubts. Thanks for the patience and the clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, -i doesn't do anything by itself; you have to actually read from the ARGV filehandle (which empty `<>` does, or the -n or -p switches).

When you do that, and -i is set, it will open the file on the command line (to the ARGV filehandle) and rename it with the extension you specify (or unlink it if you don't specify an extension) and open a new file with the original name using the ARGVOUT filehandle, selecting that as the default filehandle to print to.

Using -0777 doesn't change anything, other than that when you read from the file, you will get the entire contents, not just a line.

Comment: Thank you. I already picked an answer but if I had enough reputation, I'd at least upvote your answer.